# Links will not open from within a UIWebView

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiwebview, simulator, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm loading a local HTML file into a UIWebView when my application starts.  The file contains links (absolute URLs) to external sites.  The local file loads in the UIWebView in the iPad simulator without any issues.  However, when I click on any of the external links, the pages won't load.  I only see the progress indicator.

These same absolute URLs will open when used with a call to [webview loadRequest...] when the application starts.  And all links on those pages open properly in the UIWebView as well.  For example, I can start with http://www.google.com, perform a search, and go to any of the pages in the results.

So a couple of questions:

Why this difference in behavior between links on an HTML page loaded locally and one loaded from an external web site?

How do I get the UIWebView to open links to external sites that are on an HTML page that was initially loaded locally?

Thanks